When does $m(\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} E_n) = m(E) = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} E_n$ hold?
Suppose $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a countable family of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $m$ is the standard Lebesgue measure. We know that if $E_n \nearrow E$, then
$$m(\lim_{n \to \infty} E_n) = m(E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} E_n$$
and a similar result holds for $E_n \searrow E$ when we know that for some $k$, $m(E_k) < \infty$. But does this exchanging of limits and measures hold when $E_n$'s dont converge to a set $E$? In this case, we must weaken our language to using limsup and liminf. Thus, my question is $-$ under what circumstances are we allowed the analagous result:
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} m(E_n) = m \left( \limsup_{n \to \infty} E_n \right)$$
or similarly, when are we allowed the analogous result:
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} m(E_n) = m \left( \liminf_{n \to \infty} E_n \right)$$
I Googled this and couldn't find anything anywhere regarding it. Thanks!

You mean $\limsup {n \rightarrow \infty} E_n=\bigcap{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k$ right?

@Konstruktor Yes

Note that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} E_n$ is the countable intersection of a decreasing sequence of sets. So if $m(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k) < \infty$ for some $n$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} m(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k) = m(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k)$, in particular is equal to the superior limit. I think that something similar can be do with the inferior limit
